# On the isotropy of materials

Tags: classical-mechanics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

I am working on honeycomb structures and first of all I would like to understand whether it is isotropic or not, and, if the latter holds, which kind of anisotropy does it have?

How to do it? I don't have any elasticity matrix.

Suggestions and literature are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Honeycomb structures are certainly anisotropic. For example, the elasticity modulus in the direction orthogonal to the faces of the structures is much higher than in other directions. Please see the details in http://www.hexcel.com/Resources/DataSheets/Brochure-Data-Sheets/Honeycomb_Sandwich_Design_Technology.pdf at the site of a manufacturer of honeycombs. You will also need to find the specifications for the specific structures you are going to use.

Answer (score 0):

you have to work within the framework of the brilloin zone on this honeycomb problem .
It has non continous translational invariances so you can't really say it's isotropic...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brillouin_zone